# Integrar Sweet alert 2 python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hola amigos quien tiene algún ejemplo donde pueda integrar sweetalert con flask estoy empezando con flask y no encuentro la forma espero me puedan orientar les agradezco de antemano gracias amigos

Comment: Flask es un webframework y Sweet alert 2 funciona dentro de una página html. En realidad no es necesario flask para poder implementar el último. Mira estos ejemplos para ver si te ayudan: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo @Alberto Castillo tienes toda la razon cuando estamos utilizando flash para mostrar mensajes entre paginas entonces en nuestro alert tenemos que crear un script de javascript para que nos muestre el alert algo asi:

```
        <!-- sweetAlert2 -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
        <!-- Generamos una nueva variable de messages con sweetalert2 -->
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                    {% if category == 'error' %}
                        <script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                position: 'center',
                                icon: 'error',
                                text: "{{message}}",
                                showConfirmButton: true,
                                timer: 5000
                            })
                        </script>
                    {% else %}
                        <script>
                            Swal.fire({
                                position: 'center',
                                icon: 'success',
                                text: "{{message}}",
                                showConfirmButton: true,
                                timer: 5000
                            })
                        </script>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith  %}
```

Espero les sirva para que puedan utilizar sweetaler2 con flask o cualquier otro tipo de framework de python